# RNFetchBlob blocked firebase/firestore call react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a react native app that uses Firebase/firestore. For uploading images, I am using "react-native-fetch-blob" to create a Blob.

I am trying to fetch doc from firestore, but my app is blocked and not getting any response from firestore (not catch / nothing => just passing thru the code).

Is there anything I can do for getting docs from firestore?

Below is my code

```
import firebase from "../../../firebaseConfig";
import RNFetchBlob from "react-native-fetch-blob";

// Prepare Blob support
window.XMLHttpRequest = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.XMLHttpRequest;
const Blob = RNFetchBlob.polyfill.Blob;
const fs = RNFetchBlob.fs;
window.Blob = Blob;
const originalXMLHttpRequest = window.XMLHttpRequest;
const originalBlob = window.Blob;

var firebaseUid = "";

componentDidMount = async () => {
firebaseUid = await firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
this.getMyStory();
};

 getMyStory = async () => {
  window.XMLHttpRequest = originalXMLHttpRequest;
  window.Blob = originalBlob;
  var docRef = await firebase
   .firestore()
   .collection("demo")
   .doc(firebaseUid)
   .collection("ArrayDoc");
  docRef
  .get()
  .then(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("error", JSON.stringify(error));
  });
};
```

Error Screen
[image]

Comment: Have you tried allowing read and write to all inside the rules console?

Comment: @Perniferous  my security rules are defined as public

Comment: and before adding "react-native-fetch-blob" i have successfully fetched docs from firestore